# How to check if row already exists in csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to make a combined csv file from old files, which have some duplicates, but something is wrong in my code. 'test2.csv' is bigger and has new rows and 'test1.csv' is the new file I'm trying to make.

```
new = []
with open('test1.csv','rb') as file1:
    reader = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',' )
    with open('test2.csv','rb') as file2:
        reader2 = csv.reader(file2,delimiter=',')
        for row in reader2:
            if row not in reader:
                new.append(row)

for row in new:
    print row
```

EDIT:

My test files look like this
test1.csv:

```
28/11 16    VwS (10)    Ha MaSSe (16)   mirage  Global Offensive Champions League Season 5  39247   6756    7472    2596    10  16  8459,9434,11307,9410,8460   11838,11837,12943,11840,12944
28/11 16    Ulti (0)    Signature (16)  mirage  fpsGOD Super League Winter  39251   7343    6774    2533    0   16  12429,12427,12430,12428,12431   9288,10664,9289,11248,12129
```

test2.csv:

```
28/11 16    Singularity (14)    Elements (16)   nuke    Global Offensive Champions League Season 5  39252   6978    7489    2596    14  16  9317,2822,8862,8875,7463    8726,7405,8727,8368,8410
28/11 16    eSuba (9)   Pathless (16)   cache   Gauntlet: Fight for the Crown   39253   5412    7433    2430    9   16  9666,10458,7723,9358,3143   9891,9412,12767,12945,12766
28/11 16    Pathless (16)   eSuba (13)  mirage  Gauntlet: Fight for the Crown   39248   7433    5412    2430    16  13  9412,12945,12767,9891,12766 9666,7723,10458,9961,9358,3143
28/11 16    VwS (10)    Ha MaSSe (16)   mirage  Global Offensive Champions League Season 5  39247   6756    7472    2596    10  16  8459,9434,11307,9410,8460   11838,11837,12943,11840,12944
28/11 16    Ulti (0)    Signature (16)  mirage  fpsGOD Super League Winter  39251   7343    6774    2533    0   16  12429,12427,12430,12428,12431   9288,10664,9289,11248,12129
```

So, I'm trying to add the missing rows to the test1.csv from test2.csv.

Comment: What problem have you encountered when executing your script?

Comment: It prints every row even if the files are identical. I just want it to print the rows that are only in other csv file.

Comment: Can you clarify with a few lines of what is in test1 and test2? if you are trying to create a file called test1.csv, why would there be any lines in it when you initially read it?  seems like a logic issue more than coding.

Comment: thanks for the info. I've edited the answer to include a check on the test1 lines too.  When you wrote `if row not in reader`, that's the point at which the reader was fully iterated.  subsequent calls to that method would not return any lines, as that first loop fully reads in all the lines from the file. the file cursor would be at the end, and there would be no more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `test1.csv` isn't being modified in your snippet.  When the reader is created with `csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',')`, the `reader` is not updated at all afterwards.

You *are* modifiying `new` in your loop, so check if your line is in there.
If you want to not print out the rows that are already in test1.csv, you need to read them in and check if they are not duplicates when iterating over the rows in the second file.

```
with open('test1.csv','rb') as file1:
    existingLines = [line for line in csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')]

new = []
with open('test2.csv','rb') as file2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(file2,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader2:
        if row not in new and row not in existingLines:
            new.append(row)

for row in new:
    print row
```

Comment: It isn't the two loops that fixed it, but storing the lines in `existingLines`. That csv.reader is an iterator rather than a full list of all the rows in the file.